# How can I enable a button in one form from another?

Tags: c#

Im making a maze and I want to have my "level 2" button (in the main form) enabled when the player finishes level 1(in form 1).
So what should I do?

Comment: How do you create and display `form 1`?  Can you post the code for that bit?

Comment: `MainForm.Level2Button.Enabled = true;`

Comment: Accessing another form is no different than accessing any other object in C#. If the methods/fields are public and you have an instance, reference to an instance or those fields are static, then you can use them just the same as you would any other classes properties/methods. That may not be the best practice (idk cause I don't work on silly forms :) but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new event on the LevelForm, such as:

```
public event Action LevelCompleted;
```

Fire that event when the level is completed:

```
//run this code as soon as you know the level is completed
if(LevelCompleted != null)
    LevelCompleted();
```

Then have the main form subscribe to that event and do...whatever, when the level is completed:

```
level1Form.LevelCompleted += () => level2Button.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: +1 the shorter response to this never ending question